# `TYPE` but then in NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm, masm, sizeof

I know there are `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` in MASM, but what about NASM? As I found, it doesn't have these.

For example:

```
array   dw 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d
arrSize db $-array         ;4 elements * 2 bytes (size of one element) = 8 bytes
```

This is how I can make alternative of `SIZEOF array` in NASM. If I want the number of array elements, I can divide *arrSize* by 2 (if array elements are words). But if array elements are double words (32-bit), I need to divide by 4.

Is there an alternative for `TYPE` from MASM in NASM? If not, how can I make the program determine the size of the element itself?

Comment: You can make some macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NASM keeps its directives simple and with minimal automagic features.
It doesn't seem to be corresponding directives for the MASM `type`, `sizeof` and `length` operators.
Luckily, NASM took a much better approach than introducing heavy typing in assembly: it developed a very rich and expressive macro system.

Consider this simple macro:

```
;array <label>, <item directive>, <items>
%macro array 4-*
    %1: %2 %{3}                         ;label: db/dw/dd/... <firstItem>    
    %%second: %2 %{4:-1}                ;Local label (to get item size) and rest of the items
    
    %1_size EQU $ - %1                  ;Size of the array in bytes (here - label)
    %1_type EQU %%second - %1           ;Size of an item in bytes (second - label)
    %1_lengthof EQU %1_size / %1_type   ;Number of items (size of array /  size of item)
%endmacro
```

You can use it like `array my_array, dd, 1, 2, 3`. Not exactly like `my_array dd 1, 2, 3` but close.
Then you have:

- `my_array_size`. Size of the array in bytes.
- `my_array_type`. Size of one array item in bytes.
- `my_array_lengthof`. Number of items in the array.

You can tweak the macro to adapt it to your personal style (eg: to generate `my_array.size` and similar or make `arrdb`, `arrdw`, `arrdd` variants that implicitly take the item declaration directive).

Example:

```
BITS 32

;array <label>, <item directive>, <items>
%macro array 4-*
    %1: %2 %{3}             ;label: db/dw/dd/... <firstItem>    
    %%second: %2 %{4:-1}            ;Local label, to get item size
    
    %1_size EQU $ - %1          ;Size of the array in bytes (here - label)
    %1_type EQU %%second - %1       ;Size of an item in bytes (second - label)
    %1_lengthof EQU %1_size / %1_type   ;Number of items (size of array /  size of item)
%endmacro


;To test, use ndisam -b32
mov eax, my_array_size
mov eax, my_array_type
mov eax, my_array_lengthof
mov eax, DWORD [my_array]


;The array (ignore on output from ndisasm)
array my_array, dd, 1, 2, 3
```

Using `ndisam -b32` on the generated binary:

```
00000000  B80C000000        mov eax,0xc
00000005  B804000000        mov eax,0x4
0000000A  B803000000        mov eax,0x3
0000000F  A114000000        mov eax,[0x14]
00000014  <REDACTED GARBAGE>
```

Comment: Good work, but I believe the `%%second: %2 %{4:-1}` line wouldn't work well if there's no parameter `%4`.

Comment: @ecm Thanks, that's a good point indeed! I'll have the macro have four parameters. After all, it makes sense to use an array if you have at least two elements (otherwise `db` and similar suffice).

Comment: I might have done `%1.size equ ...` to use NASM's standard `global.local` scoping naming scheme, like you'd get from `foo: stuff` / `.size equ $ - foo`.  To use just `.size` in this case for the definition, you might need the EQU directives before the `%%second` line, but that's fine, you can do a forward reference `.size equ %%second - %1`.  Although your way has a readability advantage in terms of keeping the data part of the definition together, so maybe just changing `%1_size` to `%1.size` would be best.  Your `_` names are unlikely to conflict, but `.` names are even less likely.

Comment: @PeterCordes [NASM uses `_` for structs](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15/html/nasmdoc5.html), so I modelled the macro after it. But yeah, I also though `.` felt more right. I went with the `_` and pointed out to OP that they can change it based on their personal taste.